# Row division for even number rows

Tags: r, division

I am trying to **divide** the *first row with second*, *third row with fourth* , *fifth row with sixth* and onward for a fairly large data table. Is there any way to do it without much computation.

**Input**

```
Name Month Income
John Jan 10000 
John_County Jan 20000 
Tanya Jan 20000 
Tanya_County Jan 40000
```

**Output**

```
Name Month Per_Income
John Jan 50%
Tanya Jan 50%
```

Comment: `Is there any way to do it without much computation` what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying few R codes. But those are rudimentary .. ll[2,3] / ll[1,3] .. where "ll" is the data frame...

Comment: I think you forgot to add [tag:javascript], [tag:python], [tag:c], [tag:php] and many other tag, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg . oh sorry. shall I do it now. Jokes apart , I have these tools at my disposal and hence mentioned them.

Comment: That is, are you looking for an R, Excel, SAS, or Alteryx solution? It doesn't really make sense that you would be interested in all of them. Please remove the tags you're not interested in.

Comment: Got it. Edited the message. thanks for the help. However I believe having more tags makes question outreached to few more people and personally I have gained a lot. Is there any downside of having more tags.

Comment: The downside is that it spends others' time. The purpose of tags is not for you to draw attention to the post, but rather for potential answerers to find questions that they'll find interesting.

Comment: Try `Per_Income <- II[c(F,T),3] / II[c(T,F),3]`

Comment: You will need to fix the income column first - the commas will upset any code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R you can use an even and odd index:

```
odds <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
II[odds,"Per_Income"] <- paste0(II[odds,3] / II[!odds,3] * 100,"%")
II[odds,]
#    Name Month Income Per_Income
# 1  John   Jan  10000        50%
# 3 Tanya   Jan  20000        50%
```

Comment: @pierre, sweet. Thanks for sharing the structure. I can build something on top of it

Comment: Do you really need a character column here? Wouldn't it be more practical to leave it as a double?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a 'look ahead' merge, by offsetting the merged dataset by a single observation :

```
data want ;
  merge have 
        have (firstobs=2 rename=(Income=Next_Income)) ;
  if mod(_n_,2) = 1 then do ;
    /* 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. row */
    Per_Income = Income / Next_Income ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;
```

Comment: @LonelySoul I wish I can downvote you again. The logic is the same. _Pretend_ to put in some effort eh?

Comment: @findwindow . I can understand your pain. However I am curious if you do have any solution and if yes then why don't you help us by sharing it.

Comment: @LonelySoul this is why you don't add a `SAS` tag unless you want a `SAS` answer.